# How to send two parameters using session and cookie between two PHP files

Tags: php, session, cookies

I would like to send two parameters, "Full name" and "CourseID" using session variable from one PHP to another.
Also, I would like to set a cookie variable with my fav programming language and fav operating system.
How can I do that?
Here is my code in first.php [ sending file ]

```
<?php 
      $_SESSION['fullname'] = 'Jeyanthi Meenakshisundaram';
     $_SESSION['courseid'] = 'IT-2600';
      $favlanguage = 'JavaScript';
      $favoperatingsystem = 'iOS';
      $expire = strtotime('+1 year');
      $path = '/';
      $lifetime = 60 * 60 * 24 * 14;
          session_set_cookie_params( $lifetime, $path);
        session_start();

    
      setcookie($favlanguage, $favoperatingsystem, $expire, $path);
      
      
   ?>
****
Here is my second file which gets the value and prints:

***** 
<?php
     echo "The cookies sent are: <br/>";
     print_r($_COOKIE);    //output the contents of the cookie array variable
```

Comment: take array for storing multiple values

Comment: What is the issue you are encounter? If you `print_r($_SESSION)`, you will get all session variables too.

Comment: Is there anything not working with the code you've shared? What have you tried to resolve the problem?